# Check if matrix is scalar multiple of another python

Tags: python, numpy

```
def scalar_multiple(A,B):    
    #return A is 2*B
```

```
A = [[1,0],[0,1]]
B = [[0.5, 0],[0,0.5]]

print(is_scalar_multiple(A,B))
```

Should print 2

Comment: What did you try? This looks like a request for someone to do your homework for you.

Comment: I tried to multiply A with the inverse of B( using np.linalg.inv) using np.matul, and if the resultant matrix is a scalar multiple of identity matrix by comparing the first element of the matrix.

Comment: Why assume that `B` is invertible?

Comment: I did not think that through I suppose. However, luckily in my case, they are necessarily invertible.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_scalar_multiple(A,B):    
    possibleAnswer = A[0][0]/B[0][0] # if they are scalar multiples, this will be the answer
    errorLimit = 10e-10 # our error tolerance, it might be that our floats don't match exactly but according to this error limit they have to match till 11th decimal
    # checking one element at a time
    for i,v in enumerate(A):
        for j in range(len(v)):
            if abs(A[i][j]-(B[i][j]*possibleAnswer))>errorLimit:
                return False # even if one element fails return False
    return possibleAnswer # if everything goes correct return the possible answer
A = [[1,0],[0,1]]
B = [[0.5, 0],[0,0.5]]

print(is_scalar_multiple(A,B))
```

```
2.0
```

This won't work if denominator in the finding `possibleAnswer` is 0

You can easily handle that with if-else

Comment: What about division by `0`? It could very well be the case that `A[0][0] = B[0][0] = 0.0` but that `A` is nevertheless a scalar multiple of `B`.

Comment: well in these special cases, it would need handling

Comment: Well if we know the 'possibleAnswer', we can use more sophisticated numpy libraries to check.